Light leaking in reflections with Eevee Next
I've run into an issue in Blender 4.2 with the new version of Eevee. In the reflections, light objects seem to go through other objects. I've tried adjusting just about every Eevee related setting to mitigate the issue, to no avail.

Turning jittered shadows off makes it even worse which could imply the issue is related to it somehow.

Replacing the area light with a mesh light yields correct behavior in the reflections but then the illuminating effect of the light object is lost.

I'm wondering if anyone knows what is going on here and if there's a solution/workaround for this issue?
